# Не выравнивается псевдоэлемент

Tags: html, css

Мне нужно немного подвинуть картинку сверху, чтобы было ровно. Но когда я пишу margin, текст отступается тоже. Хотя если сделать border показывается, что картинка отдельно существует. Пробовал текст в спан оборачивать, но все равно оно вместе передвигается

html:

```
<a class="link" target="blank" href="#">full story</a>
```

css:

```
.link {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 40px 0px 50px 0px ;
    background:  rgb( 128, 183, 179 );
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 17px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 0px 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color:white;
}

.link::after {
    content: url('img/Shape2.png');
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px 0px 0px 10px;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выравнивание с помощью отступов и полей - плохая практика. Правильнее будет использовать *flex*:

```css
.link {
  margin: 40px 0px 50px 0px;
  
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 10px;
  
  height: 40px; width: 200px;
  padding: 0px 30px;
  border-radius: 17px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  background: rgb(128, 183, 179);
}

.link::after {
  content: "";
  background: center / cover url("https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/545/545682.png") no-repeat;
  height: 24px; width: 24px;
}
```

```html
<a class="link" target="blank" href="#">full story</a>
```